# Flood fill in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I got a task to do. I need to run a Flood Fill algorithm on CUDA. On CPU I have a non-recursive method with queue, but I dont have any idea how to do move this code to GPU so that it would run faster. Can anybody help?

edit:
this is my CPU code, just normal FloodFill with my little modifications

```
void cpuFloodFill(std::vector<std::vector<int>> *colorVector, int node)
{
    std::queue<int> q;
    q.push(node);

    int i,j;

    while(!q.empty())
    {
        int k = q.front();
        q.pop();

        k2ij(k, &i, &j);
        if((*colorVector)[i][j] == COLOR_TARGET)
        {
            (*colorVector)[i][j] = COLOR_REPLACEMENT;           
            if(i - 1 >= 0 && i - 1 < X && j >= 0 && j < Y)
                q.push(ij2k(i - 1, j));

            if(i + 1 >= 0 && i + 1 < X && j >= 0 && j < Y)
                q.push(ij2k(i + 1, j));

            if(i >= 0 && i < X && j - 1 >= 0 && j - 1 < Y)
                q.push(ij2k(i, j - 1));

            if(i >= 0 && i < X && j + 1 >= 0 && j + 1 < Y)
                q.push(ij2k(i, j + 1));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can you give you're CPU code? It's really hard to help you with no information

Answer (score 1):

There's a GPU flood fill implementation in an image skeletonization toolkit named [CUDA Skel](http://www.cs.rug.nl/svcg/Shapes/CUDASkel). The link to its source code is on the website. Please note the license of the code: the source and toolkit are free for research purposes with due citation.